# For loop utilizing != for string character not working in Python

Tags: python, python-3.4

I am a beginner learning Python 3.4, and am working on a program where I read bits from the user, and determine the parity bit based on an even parity.

I am doing a check to see if the user enters the correct 8 bits, and if they are entering 1 or 0 only.

The user is entering the value using the input() function, and is entered as a string.  My error comparison function is as follows:

```
#Check for errors in user defined string
def errors(check):
    for i in check:
        if (i != '1' or i != '0') and len(check) == 8:
            result = 0 #return value means not binary, but right amount of digits
            #break
        elif (i != '1' or i != '0') and len(check) != 8:
            result = 1 #Not binary and wrong amout of digits
            break
        elif len(check) != 8:
            result = 2 #wrong amount of digits but binary
            break
        elif (i == '1' or i == '0'):
            result = 3 #Binary, and correct amount of digits
        else:
            print('Error checking loop messed up')
    return result
```

basically my first if statement is executing (even though I am entering in 10101010), or my second if statement (101010101010, or 1010ag1010 something like that).

my output is as follows:

> `enter a string of bits (must be 1 or 0, max. 8): 10101010`
>
> `You entered a value that is not a 1 or 0`

The program is not recognizing my 1's and 0's for some reason.  Any help to point me in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: so you want the length to be a maximum of 8 not exact 8 chars?

Comment: Where is `'You entered a value that is not a 1 or 0'` in the code you posted?

Comment: Just confirming: you are using python3, yes?

Comment: I am looking for the string to be exactly 8 characters.

Comment: variable check is the input string which is written like this user_input = input('enter a string of bits (must be 1 or 0, max. 8): ')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all , the first `if` condition is wrong -

```
if (i != '1' or i != '0') and len(check) == 8:
```

Why? Because lets say `i` is `1` so in first part of the condition , we see that `i` is not equal to `0` , so it is True, and in second part if `check` is equal to `8` , we enter the if condition.

It should ideally be an `and` -

```
if (i != '1' and i != '0') and len(check) == 8:
```

Similarly, use `and` in second condition as well.

---

But given that, I think you should ideally consider length of the string and each character being `1` or `0` as completely different and instead return back a list, where one element indicates whether the length of the array is correct or not, and the second element indicates whether the characters are all `1` and `0` or not.

Example -

```
def errors(check):
    result = []
    if len(check) == 8:
        result.append(1)
    else:
        result.append(0)
    for i in check:
        if i not in {'1','0'}:
            result.append(0)
            break
    else:
        result.append(1)
    return result
```

Then you can compare against this list in your main code (or wherever you call the function from, and decide what all were wrong).

It would return `0` in first element if length is wrong, 1 otherwise.

It would return `1` in second element if all characters are either `1` or `0` , `0` otherwise.

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot.  I see the and issue now, and I appreciate the alternate solution, it is a much better way.